# react-native FlatList onViewableItemsChanged squirrely behaviour

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've connected onViewableItemsChanged in my FlatList. I am using the config below. I do see the debug console.log()s that I expect so that's good. What is strange, however, is that if I scroll only a few pixels up and down, keeping the same row on-screen at all times, the changes indicate the item coming and going from the visibility set. Am I interpreting the logging wrong maybe?

```
  viewabilityConfig = {
    minimumViewTime: 1000,
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
    waitForInteraction: false
  };

console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(0), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(1), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(0), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(1), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(0), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(1), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(0), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: Object {viewableItems: Array(1), changed: Array(1)}
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: viewableItems  7892022976039774682
console.js:26 onViewableItemsChanged: changed  7892022976039774682
```

Comment: can you share more code with us

Comment: thanks for your attention & time. i can't post code. we've moved to ListView since FlatList was giving us performance issues as well. was just wondering if anybody else has seen strange behaviour with the viewableitems.